# Unknown class specified for dataClass - ProGuard

Tags: java, android, kotlin, proguard

I need some help, i've activated the proguard for code obfuscation but when i launch the app, crash and logcat print this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application eu.reply.lea.mobile.core.showcase.ShowcaseApplication: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown class specified for dataClass: eu.reply.lea.mobile.core.oldies.entity.User

...

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown class specified for dataClass: eu.reply.lea.mobile.core.oldies.entity.User
```

In the proguard file i added this lines but doesn't change nothing.

```
-keepclassmembernames class eu.reply.lea.mobile.core.oldies.entity.User {
    public *;
}

-keepclassmembernames class eu.reply.lea.mobile.core.showcase.ShowcaseApplication {
    public *;
}
```

Tried to add @keep and @keepnames annotations in user but nothing changed.

How can i solve this?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why these errors are showing up can have 2 causes:

1. This class has been removed because of shrinking
2. This class relies on reflection

I would suggest adding the following keeprule to your proguard configuration file:

```
-keep class eu.reply.lea.mobile.core.oldies.entity.User
```

A useful tool you can use to check what parts of your code will be affected when you define this keeprule can be found [here](https://playground.proguard.com/p/RXZ1ob).